# Duplication server name in URL

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, localhost, virtualhost

I have a trouble with configure of Apache and Tomcat. My purpose is to get ability to adress to `tui.org/servlet`, when `tui.org` is my virtual host configured on local machine and `/servlet/` is `url-pattern` which is defined at `web.xml`. But instead the servelet I get 404 Not Found by Tomcat but I can to adress to my server by `tui.org/tui.org/servlet` - it works. Structure of files on my server is the following:

```
Root: /var/www/tui.org
-------->/WEB-INF/classes/a
-------->/WEB-INF/classes/a/MainServlet.class
-------->/WEB-INF/web.xml
-------->/index.html
```

How can I achieve this behaviour?

web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My server.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="/var/www/"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Configuration of tui.org (tui.org.conf at /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tui.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tui.org

    <Directory /var/www/tui.org>
        AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    JkMount /servlet* ajp13_worker
</VirtualHost>
```

I use Apache2, tomcat9 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving problem with adressing by `tui.org/servlet` I had to add `<Context>` directive to `server.xml`:

```
<Context path="" docBase="/var/www/tui.org/"/>
```

and change `appBase` from `/var/www/` to `/var/www/tui.org/`.

And for fix problem with access to `WEB-INF` (thanks to @OlafKock) I had to add next to `tui.org.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/tui.org>
    AllowOverride All
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here:

- You **must not** serve the web application directory with Apache - e.g. you're declaring `DocumentRoot /var/www/tui.org` for Apache and `<Host appBase="/var/www/">` for Tomcat.

  - e.g but not limited to: The servlet spec specifically disallows to serve the directory WEB-INF to ever be served to a client, and you're explicitly bypassing this limitation.
- An application deployed in a `Host`'s `appBase` is always deployed under that name (unless specified differently in a context.xml file). The only other exception to that rule is if a directory is called `ROOT` - in that case, it's deployed without a name, thus omitting the tui.org that follows your server name.

  - but this is secondary to the issue of serving the whole webapp through Apache httpd. Fix *that one* first.

One way to fix your biggest problem is to omit the `DocumentRoot` directive in Apache and rather serve everything from Tomcat: `JkMount * ajp13_worker`.

Comment: But I want to process static files (e.g. html/css/gif/etc) by apache and servlets/jsp by tomcat. It (`JkMount * ajp13_worker`) doesn't allow to do this. Apache can deny access for all for `WEB-INF`. `webapps` is a mistake - I have pasted old configuration files. The question have solved. Now I post answer.